# Create or extend web application in central administration link missing

Tags: sharepoint

Lately the link to create web applications in central administration for sharepoint server simply isn't there anymore. How can I get it back?

Answer (score 1):

I answer my question by myself to help someone in the same situation. It cost me 2 whole days to figure it out: There is a user that has more rights than any other in the system, even if the other users belong to administrators. That is the user with whom the system initially got installed. This user was deactivated by me right after installation because of possible security problems. Log on with this user and voila: The link to create web applications is immediatly shown again. I had to activate this user and log-in as whim. User-change in central administration doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If the user you are logged on as does not have that permission, the link will not be seen.  Has your permission level changed?

Comment: There is only one active user - since this is a test server. I'm the administrator of the server (w2k8). Is there a special group to which the user needs to be added? Every other administrative tasks are working perfectly well by the way.

Answer (score 0):

i find the solution , 
i am using windows 7 machine , so in windows 7 user administrator is disable and has no password , so for login into Sharepoint as admin u need use administrator account . to solve this problem u can use this steps . 
1. in computer management -> local user and groups -> Administrator

2. enable account , and set new password
3. login as administrator into sharepoint ,

enjoy it

javadparvaresh[at]yahoo.com